# How can one acquire a language just by listening without the visuals?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning

I have watched Stephen Krashen's talk on language acquisition.

And I learnt that according to decades of research and experience, the best way to pick up a new language is to *acquire* - just like children do - via comprehensible input.

This works great when interacting with language partners / parents, or when watching videos online where one can see things being shown or pointed at.

**My question is:**

- How can one acquire a language when watching or seeing is not an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advantages of audio-only courses compared to more traditional ones](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/112/advantages-of-audio-only-courses-compared-to-more-traditional-ones)

Comment: Ergh, no. Does that answer my question for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the popular methods of audio-only is [Pimsleur Method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimsleur_Language_Programs). Instead of visuals, it uses explanations in L1. Quite effective, IMHO.

Comment: thank you!!.....